# A more efficient way to get post views using the facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, object, facebook-graph-api

I am using the facebook api to read the `post_impressions` field from a pages `insights` object. The problem is, you can only back a result for 1 single post, or a result that shows all impressions from all posts in a month/week/day, this means you cannot get back a result that shows all posts with their corresponding `post_impressions`.

The way I got it to work as I want now is by looping my facebook posts and within that loop I put a file_get_contents for the `insights` object and just add a looped post id inside the url.

This way every post I get, a new request is made to the FB api which takes a heavy toll on loading times.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? When I remove that part of my code, my site loads way faster.

Here is a summary of my code to get a better idea:

```
$json_object = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/367712570004555/posts?fields=comments,full_picture,likes,message,picture,story,permalink_url,updated_time,from&access_token=12303302670122ZDzN5ucp8JzMf5VBDdY");

$feedarray = json_decode($json_object);

foreach ($feedarray->data as $key => $feed_data)
{
    $json_insights = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/".$feed_data->id."/insights/post_impressions?access_token=EAACEdEose0cBANjKErkMLhCgmZBBrgLn8KtZBW2d6JbWz7sZAivld67JxvP8MqyZCs9xg3Bh11lzETOwd64LIpAPp3zbstu8ELFZC8HOwYyxckqJ60WQcVL1FqB3iy5L3oRCsFSQA7MzHGgcqIYxsjAlJomYrOMZCqo6PwZDZD");

    $views = $insights->data[0]->values[0]->value;

    echo $views;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Field Expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion) syntax to get this all in one go:

```
.../367712570004555/posts?fields=comments,...,insights.metric(post_impressions)
```

Comment: Alright great, one quick question (if its big enough for a new post on SO I'll post one). How can i change the access token into a permanent one? Because all of a sudden I get a bad request and when I check the request I see: `Error validating access token: Session has expired on Tuesday, 26-Sep-17 03:00:00 PDT. The current time is Tuesday, 26-Sep-17 03:05:13 PDT.`

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension explains how to extend token lifetime.