# Facebook API showing post messages and shares but not reactions or insights

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-access-token, facebook-insights

Based on Graph API Explorer GET v7.0 I want to fetch all posts published by a given FB profile, with some basic statistics (views, reactions, comments, shares, the message)

I tried ****ProfileID/posts?fields=shares,message,**reactions,insights**

The script fetches all posts with their shares and messages, but nothing on reactions or insights - these are greyed (**"Field is empty or disallowed by the access token"**).

I have tried both User Access Token and Page Access Token, granted the token all availabel permissions and debugged it.

Interestingly, when I deep dive into a single post, I can fetch count of likes of its comments, e.g.the following script returns likes for each comment

ProfileID_PostID?fields=comments{message,like_count}

Please help me to get anyhow access to views/'seen', reactions, insights etc - whatever it takes to count user reactions to each post

Thanks

Piotr

Comment: Insights are not a thing for user posts to begin with. And for reactions on user posts, I am guessing what it says on top of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v7.0/object/reactions applies here - _“[…], except that for the following nodes, /reactions doesn't return a profile except for the current user, if read with a user access token: […] Post”_ - I am interpreting that as, for user posts, you can only get your _own_ reaction, if you are using your own user token. Any other reactions on user posts, are not available to you.

Comment: So at most you will be able to get the summaries for reactions, but you will have to explicitly ask for those then.

Comment: Thanks CBroe. Actually, for a few posts I do get singular reactions of other users (FB nets inaccurate?). 
Coudl you drop a hint how to fetc summaries of reactions?

Comment: I found way to fetch summaries of metrics with 
109846400746187?fields=posts{reactions.type(CARE).summary(total_count)}
However, I can't get similar summary of views, even if following this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423138/a-more-efficient-way-to-get-post-views-using-the-facebook-api
This script does not work
109846400746187/posts?fields=message,shares,insights.metric(post_impressions)
Any idea how to currently fetch views for each post?